# Why does filterv's predicate need to be free of side-effects?

Tags: clojure, side-effects

I'm *finally* learning Box2D (using the [cljbox2d port](https://github.com/floybix/cljbox2d/tree/master/cljbox2d)). During my "hello world tests", I found the need for a function that checks a list of boxes, destroying and removing from the list the out of bounds ones.

The basic function that I wrote up to handle this is`*`:

```
(defn handle-out-of-bounds! [boxes]
  (filterv (fn [{:keys [body]}]
             (when-not (inbounds? (bc/position body))
               (bc/destroy! body)))
           boxes))
```

The thing of note here is that `destroy!`, as its name suggests, carries out side effects.

I decided for kicks to check out the source of `filterv` since I never actually had, and noticed the doc-string had the warning:

> . . . pred must be free of side-effects.

*Why?* `filter` I can see. It's lazy, so you don't have a guarantee that the predicate will actually run at any given point unless you explicitly force the evaluation. `filterv` however is a strict reduction over the list; internally using a transient vector. The only thing of suspect is the use of transients, but I don't see how that would effect anything.

Is there *actually* an effective reason not to carry out side effects in `filterv`'s predicate, or is it simply a conceptual reason?

---

`*` I realized after  writing it that my logic was off, and that this function is actually broken, but that's besides the point here. I could have also handled the destruction and removal separately, but again, that's besides the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other people have puzzled over this before, see for example the same question in [this mailing list post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/clojure/81iWQSC2N20/Jp1uPq8vCAAJ).

Those who have commented also seem to agree that the statement in question is unmotivated. `filterv` is eager, a side-effecting `pred` is not problematic.

If the statement is wrong, a probable explanation is a simple copy-and-paste error in the doc string. `mapv` and `filterv` [were introduced by Stuart Halloway](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/commit/ec59ebac31d1d6722793f988685154c83232f964), who simply copied the doc strings of `map` and `filter` with ‘vector’ substituted for ‘lazy sequence’.

Comment: Since this is speculation, I'm going to wait to see if anything else comes in, but I wouldn't be surprised if you're right.

Comment: I have opened [CLJ-2452](https://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-2452) … let’s see how that goes.

Comment: Cool, thanks. It would be nice to have this clarified/fixed.